# Deployment Options for Prism Apps for

Tags: wpf, deployment, installation, prism

Does anyone have any experience with deployment options for Prism Apps?

[I tried](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405497%28PandP.40%29.aspx) ClickOnce and found it to be too [buggy](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/workitem/7546) and too [hard for my users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197333/clickonce-does-not-work-with-windows-uninstall) (With Prism 4 and .NET 4).

Clearly I could just go make a normal installer using installshield or something.  But what I really want is something that lets me leverage the fact that my app is in modules.

Something that will allow me to re-deploy a single changed module/dll and not have to require re-deploying the whole application.

Is there anything out there (besides ClickOnce) that works that way?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

http://wyday.com/wyupdate/

Though you might have to use wyBuild to use it.